# Timezone issue with grails application

Tags: tomcat, grails, timezone

I have a running Grails application with timezone set to GST as parameter to jvm on tomcat 7. Suddenly couple weeks back, the application starts misbehaving and the time I see in logs is GMT time.

Im not sure where should I look for more information, which setting is overridding the value. Any help?

Comment: What is "GST" meant to be? I would advise you to use a full IANA time zone ID (e.g. Europe/London) rather than an abbreviation.

Comment: Okay - so do you *actually* want to enforce standard time, or do you want a time zone ID that varies according to daylight saving time (if such a thing happens)? Basically, can you find an appropriate IANA time zone ID? What *location's* local time are you trying to map to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Jon Skeet suggestion, after replacing jvm parameter `user.timezone=GST` to `user.timezone=Asia/Dubai` solved the issue